# $scope objects does not get pushed into array Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays, scope

I am trying to push a scope variable into an array which I have created but it is not pushed into the array for some reasons.

For some reasons all the $scope variables like $scope.marks and others does not reflect in the array when I did the console log. Any idea how do I fix this problem or how do I push the variable inside $scope.marks into the array ?

Below is my code:

```
$scope.resultsArray.push($scope.marks)
console.log($scope.resultsArray, "array results")
```

Comment: are you getting any error? and what does `$scope.marks` contain

Comment: make sure you defined $scope.resultsArray = [];

Comment: $scope.marks contains the data i retrieved from the database, and I want to push it to an array which I will then display the array in the view. Right now when I do the console.log(console.log($scope.resultsArray, "array results"), it shows me resultsArray[1] but I want to see the contents of the array in console.log.

Comment: what does, `console.log($scope.resultsArray[0], "array results")` return?

Comment: it returns undefined, i think it wasnt push into the array

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined the *resultsArray* before pushing *marks* in it.

This should work:

## $scope.resultsArray = []; $scope.resultsArray.push($scope.marks);

*(Here I am assuming that **marks** is a model assigned to some HTML input)*

Comment: marks is the data that i have obtained from firebase database. it is a simple "90". Right now when I do the console.log(console.log($scope.resultsArray, "array results"), it shows me resultsArray[1] but I want to see the contents of the array in console.log.

Comment: @purplewind just `console.log($scope.resultsArray)` then

Comment: @purplewind Try using console.log($scope.resultsArray[0]) first to see if it is pushed in the array or not.

Comment: it is undefined. looks like it was not pushed into the array